# Detecting the release of a ball in real time

Tags: algorithm, computer-vision, real-time, video-capture, detection

I'm working on a project where I'm capturing people making free throw shots via a video camera. I need a way to detect, as fast as possible, the instant the ball is released from a player's hand. I tried researching a lot of detection/tracking  algorithms, but everything I've found seemed more suited to tracking the ball itself. While I may eventually want to do that, right now all I need to know is the release timing.

I'm also open to other solutions that don't use the camera (I have a decent budget), but of course I'd like to use the camera if possible/fast enough. I'm also able to mess with the camera positioning/setup, and what I even want in the FOV.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm pretty stuck right now, and haven't been able to find anything online that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use visual markers (motion trackers) on the throwing hands and on the ball. The precision is based on the FPS of the camera.

The assumption is that you know the ball dimension and the hand grip on the ball that may vary. By using visual markers/trackers you can know the position of the ball relative to the hand. When the distance between the initial grip of the ball and the hand is bigger than the distance between the center of the ball and it's extremity then is when you have your release. [Schema of the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8GU9.jpg)

A better solution is to use a graded meter bar (alternate between black and white bars like the ones used on the mythbusters show to track the speed of objects). At the moment there is a color gap between the hand and the ball you have your release. The downside of this approach is that you have to capture the image at a side angle or top-down angle and use panels to hold the grading.

Your problem is similar to the billiard ball collision detection. I hope you find [this paper](http://billiards.colostate.edu/physics/ajp_09_hsv_article.pdf) helpful.

Edit:

There is a powerful tool, that is not that expensive named Microsoft Kinect used for motion capture. The downside of this tool is that it's camera works with 30 fps and you cannot use it accurately on a very sunny scene. However I have found a scientific paper about using kinect to record athletes, including free-throws in basketball. [Paper here](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/705/1/012064/pdf)

It's my first answer on so. Any feedback on how to improve my future answers is appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and illustration. I think I understand your first point, but just to make sure, are you saying I should independently detect the hand and ball in every frame, until the distance criteria is satisfied? Wouldn't this be computationally very expensive? Maybe I'm not sure what kind of markers you had in mind.
I had trouble picturing your second idea (I don't watch mythbusters :/ ). Are you saying to have some type of pattern on the floor, and then detect  when that pattern appears (I think that would certainly be fast)? Or are you saying to somehow use a physical bar?

Comment: By the way, your first answer was excellent. I like that you gave references and even went so far as to hand draw an illustration of your first idea. Your answer is probably eloquent, its just that this is all new for me (video capturing/image analysis), so I have my own issues.

Comment: @JohnAlperto Yes, you should independently detect the hands and ball in everyframe, or at least on the frames that interest you, [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_capture I can't say for sure about the computational power used, but in my experience with microsoft Kinect I had no problem on tracking multiple objects on my below average laptop.

On the second ideea, here is a 1 minute youtube video of what I was saying [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLuI118nhzc